# How to Import KFServing Client Package in Golang

Tags: go, kubernetes, inference, client-go

We are using [KFServing](https://github.com/kubeflow/kfserving/tree/v0.5.1) in our kubernetes cluster. The project provides InferenceService struct and clientset in the folder pkg/.

How to import these packages under [pkg/client](https://github.com/kubeflow/kfserving/tree/v0.5.1/pkg/client)? My code is as below:

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    kfs 
   "github.com/kubeflow/kfserving/pkg/client/clientset/versioned"
)

func main() {
   var clientset   *kfs.Cientset
   clientset = kfs.NewForConfig(nil)
   fmt.Println(clientset)
}
```

Try ***go mod tidy*** i got (I need dev on specified version v0.5.1):

```
    main imports
    github.com/kubeflow/kfserving/pkg/client/clientset/versioned 
    imports
    k8s.io/client-go/discovery imports
    github.com/googleapis/gnostic/OpenAPIv2: 
     module github.com/googleapis/gnostic@latest found (v0.5.5), 
     but does not contain package 
     github.com/googleapis/gnostic/OpenAPIv2
     main imports
    github.com/kubeflow/kfserving/pkg/client/clientset/versioned 
    imports
    ...
```

Try compiling these code i got:

```
  a lot of errors .....
```

After ***go get github.com/kubeflow/kfserving*** I got:

Then I changed the go.mod and reconfiged the kfseving version from v0.6.0 to v0.5.1 and then recompile these code, still got below error:

```
go build .
 go: github.com/kubeflow/kfserving@v0.5.1: missing go.sum entry; to add it:
    go mod download github.com/kubeflow/kfserving
```

contens of go.mod:

```
module main

go 1.16

require github.com/kubeflow/kfserving v0.5.1 // indirect
```

**UPDATE**
**for kfserving v0.4.0 everything works well**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the `kfserving` `go.mod` file at `v0.5.1`, I see [a big block of `replace` directives](https://github.com/kubeflow/kfserving/blob/aa1042a3b6f72a65f16e13771ce335b1844ad7fc/go.mod#L46-L71). By design, [`replace` directives](https://golang.org/ref/mod#go-mod-file-replace) “only apply in the main module's `go.mod` file and are ignored in other modules”, so it looks like `kfserving` has some technical debt here that they're passing on to you.

I started with an empty `go.mod` file and pasted in those `replace` directives. Then:

```
$ go get -d github.com/kubeflow/kfserving/pkg/client/clientset/versioned@v0.5.1
go get: added github.com/PuerkitoBio/purell v1.1.1
…
go get: added sigs.k8s.io/yaml v1.2.0
```

The `.go` source file needed a few fixes for typos and mismatched types. I fudged it to:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    kfs "github.com/kubeflow/kfserving/pkg/client/clientset/versioned"
)

func main() {
    var clientset *kfs.Clientset
    clientset = kfs.NewForConfigOrDie(nil)
    fmt.Println(clientset)
}
```

and then `go build .` succeeds:

```
$ go build -o /dev/null .
```

Now I'll run `go mod tidy` to clean up the `go.mod` and `go.sum` files:

```
$ go mod tidy
go: downloading github.com/stretchr/testify v1.5.1
…
go: downloading github.com/jmespath/go-jmespath v0.3.0
```

---

But wait! I've still got all of the technical debt from `kfserving/go.mod` — without any comments explaining the choice of versions! — and I'm passing that technical debt on to any downstream users. Let's see if I can improve the situation while I'm here.

Go 1.16 handles the `exclude` directive a lot better than previous Go versions did, so maybe I can use a couple of targeted `exclude` directives instead of the (rather large) `replace` hammer.

I'll start by committing the fixes so far. (If nothing else, I want to be able to `git diff` the requirements to see what has changed.)

```
$ git add *.go go.mod go.sum

$ git commit -m 'fixed kfserving build'
[main fd93b1d] fixed kfserving build
 3 files changed, 1643 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 go.sum
```

I notice that all of the `replace` directives apply to `k8s.io` paths, so I'll list the current versions of those paths to see what needs to be fixed:

```
$ go list -m k8s.io/...
k8s.io/api v0.19.2 => k8s.io/api v0.19.2
k8s.io/apiextensions-apiserver v0.19.2 => k8s.io/apiextensions-apiserver v0.19.2
k8s.io/apimachinery v0.19.2 => k8s.io/apimachinery v0.19.2
k8s.io/apiserver v0.19.2 => k8s.io/apiserver v0.19.2
k8s.io/client-go v11.0.1-0.20190805182717-6502b5e7b1b5+incompatible => k8s.io/client-go v0.19.2
k8s.io/cloud-provider v0.19.2 => k8s.io/cloud-provider v0.19.2
k8s.io/code-generator v0.19.2 => k8s.io/code-generator v0.19.2
k8s.io/component-base v0.19.2 => k8s.io/component-base v0.19.2
k8s.io/csi-translation-lib v0.19.2 => k8s.io/csi-translation-lib v0.19.2
k8s.io/gengo v0.0.0-20200428234225-8167cfdcfc14
k8s.io/klog v1.0.0 => k8s.io/klog v1.0.0
k8s.io/klog/v2 v2.2.0
k8s.io/kube-openapi v0.0.0-20200805222855-6aeccd4b50c6
k8s.io/legacy-cloud-providers v0.17.4 => k8s.io/legacy-cloud-providers v0.19.2
k8s.io/test-infra v0.0.0-20200803112140-d8aa4e063646 => k8s.io/test-infra v0.0.0-20200803112140-d8aa4e063646
k8s.io/utils v0.0.0-20200912215256-4140de9c8800 => k8s.io/utils v0.0.0-20200324210504-a9aa75ae1b89
```

Most of those look fine, but there are three mismatched versions:

```
k8s.io/client-go v11.0.1-0.20190805182717-6502b5e7b1b5+incompatible => k8s.io/client-go v0.19.2
…
k8s.io/legacy-cloud-providers v0.17.4 => k8s.io/legacy-cloud-providers v0.19.2
…
k8s.io/utils v0.0.0-20200912215256-4140de9c8800 => k8s.io/utils v0.0.0-20200324210504-a9aa75ae1b89
```

`legacy-cloud-providers` just needs an upgrade, so that should be easy enough to fix with `go get` — but it's not relevant to this package anyway so I can just let it float to whatever version it ends up at. I'll cut down the `replace` directives to just the two remaining modules and see how far I get:

```
replace (
    k8s.io/client-go => k8s.io/client-go v0.19.2
    k8s.io/utils => k8s.io/utils v0.0.0-20200324210504-a9aa75ae1b89
)
```

Now:

```
$ go mod tidy

$ go build -o /dev/null .
```

Ok, so the build is still good — I've made incremental progress, so I'll lock that in:

```
$ git add go.mod go.sum

$ git commit -m 'go.mod: remove irrelevant replacements'
[main cdbc1db] go.mod: remove irrelevant replacements
 3 files changed, 456 insertions(+), 43 deletions(-)
 rewrite go.mod (85%)
 create mode 100755 m
```

Now let's try notching out the bad `client-go` versions with `exclude` directives:

```
$ go mod edit -exclude=k8s.io/client-go@v11.0.1-0.20190805182717-6502b5e7b1b5+incompatible

$ go list -m k8s.io/client-go
k8s.io/client-go v9.0.0+incompatible => k8s.io/client-go v0.19.2

$ go mod edit -exclude=k8s.io/client-go@v9.0.0+incompatible

$ go list -m k8s.io/client-go
k8s.io/client-go v0.19.2 => k8s.io/client-go v0.19.2
```

Now I'm at the `client-go` version I needed, so I can drop that `replace` directive:

```
$ go mod edit -dropreplace=k8s.io/client-go

$ go mod tidy

$ go build -o /dev/null .
```

And again lock it in:

```
$ git add go.mod go.sum

$ git commit -m 'go.mod: use exclude instead of replace to notch out unwanted client-go versions'
[main de69965] go.mod: use exclude instead of replace to notch out unwanted client-go versions
 2 files changed, 21 insertions(+), 3 deletions(-)
```

Now let's see what's going on with this `k8s.io/utils` replacement. I suspect that it isn't really needed — the version will be upgraded a bit, but I'm betting it won't break the build. And, indeed, it seems to be fine:

```
$ go list -m k8s.io/utils
k8s.io/utils v0.0.0-20200912215256-4140de9c8800 => k8s.io/utils v0.0.0-20200324210504-a9aa75ae1b89

$ go mod edit -dropreplace=k8s.io/utils

$ go mod tidy

$ go build -o /dev/null .

$ go list -m k8s.io/utils
k8s.io/utils v0.0.0-20200912215256-4140de9c8800
```

---

So now I've successfully reduced that big nest of `replace` directives from `kfserving` to just a couple of `exclude` directives targeted retracted versions of `k8s.io/client-go`. Here's my whole `go.mod` file at the end of this process:

```
module example.com/m

go 1.16

exclude (
    k8s.io/client-go v11.0.1-0.20190805182717-6502b5e7b1b5+incompatible
    k8s.io/client-go v9.0.0+incompatible
)

require github.com/kubeflow/kfserving v0.5.1
```

Answer (score -1):

This seems like a module cache issue cause that package appears to be there for [v0.5.1](https://github.com/kubeflow/kfserving/blob/v0.5.1/pkg/client/clientset/versioned/clientset.go). Do the following:

1. Clean the modcache `go clean --modcache`
2. Get the module the nice way via `go get github.com/kubeflow/kfserving@v0.5.1`
3. Run `go mod tidy`

### Update

With the extra output I can see you you have an import error from a dependent module.

```
github.com/kubeflow/kfserving/pkg/client/clientset/versioned 
    imports
    k8s.io/client-go/discovery imports
    github.com/googleapis/gnostic/OpenAPIv2:
```

So version v0.5.1 imports `k8s.io/client-go/discovery` which imports `github.com/googleapis/gnostic/OpenAPIv2` which no longer exists in the current release (but it is there is [older](https://github.com/google/gnostic/tree/v0.2.2/OpenAPIv2) releases). So it looks like you would need to fix the import version in `client-go` to avoid this issue.

Comment: go the same error. everything works fine for v0.4.0

Comment: There is nothing in the question that would lead me to suspect module cache corruption — `go clean --modcache` is an awfully big hammer, and after `go get` and `go mod tidy` the symptom in the original report remains.

Comment: @bcmills yeah i mention that in the update after they dropped more information. Very cool to see the fix done entirely with go.mod.